# Vuetify dialog component to correctly delete item from parent component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a delete dialog component that when clicking **Cancel** or **Delete** nothing happens, not even errors. What am I missing to correctly delete or cancel

```
<template>
  <v-dialog
    v-bind="$attrs"
    v-on="$listeners"
    max-width="500px"
    persistent
  >
    <v-card>
      <v-card-title
        class="headline"
      >
        {{ title }}
      </v-card-title>
      <v-card-text>
        {{ message }}
      </v-card-text>
      <v-card-actions>
        <v-spacer />
        <v-btn
          color="grey darken-1"
          text
          @click="$emit('closeDeleteDialog')"
        >
          Cancel
        </v-btn>
        <v-btn
          color="primary darken-1"
          text
          @click="$emit('deleteItem')"
        >
          Delete
        </v-btn>
      </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
  </v-dialog>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'DeleteDialog',
  props: {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    message: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    }
  },
  emits: ['closeDeleteDialog', 'deleteItem']
}
</script>
```

This is how I use my component:

```
        <DeleteDialog
          v-model="dialogDelete"
          title="Delete location"
          message="Are you sure you want to delete this location?"
        />
```

On the same view as where I import my component I have my methods.

```
export default {
  components: {
    DeleteDialog: () => import('@/components/Shared/DeleteDialog'),
  },
  data: () => ({
    locationId: null,
    dialog: false,
    dialogDelete: false,
  })
  },
  methods: {
    deleteItem () {
      this.$store.dispatch('deleteFirebaseDoc', { docId: this.locationId, collection: 'locations' })

      this.locationId = null
      this.dialogDelete = false
    },
    deleteItemConfirm (item) {
      this.locationId = item.docId
    },
    closeDeleteDialog () {
      this.dialogDelete = false
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

How can I correctly access my component to delete and item or cancel the dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the parent component you need to to listen to those events you emit

```
<DeleteDialog
  v-model="dialogDelete"
  title="Delete location"
  message="Are you sure you want to delete this location?"
  @close-delete-dialog="dialogDelete = false" // or call closeDeleteDialog () 
  @delete-item="deleteItem()"
/>
```

I've never used *camelCase* for events emitting so I'd rather write it like `$emit('close-delete-dialog')` and `$emit('delete-item')`